# Can't uninstall keras with conda

Tags: python, keras, anaconda, conda, uninstallation

I somehow installed `keras` twice(`2.2.4` and `2.3.1`) with `conda` (at least I think I did). Now I am trying to uninstall both, the first one (`2.2.4`) I could uninstall with `conda uninstall keras`. But this doesn't work for the second one.

```
(base) keras_retinanet$ conda list keras
|# packages in environment at anaconda3:
│# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
keras                     2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_0  
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_1  
keras-resnet              0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-retinanet           0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
(base) keras_retinanet$ conda uninstall keras
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment:
- keras
```

How can I uninstall the second one?

I already tried to uninstall keras with pip3:

WARNING: Skipping keras as it is not installed.

And when importing keras in python I get this path:

```
>>> keras.__path__
_NamespacePath(['.../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras'])
```

Thanks

Comment: so, as you already realized, you'll have to use `pip` to uninstall the pypi installation of keras. maybe your `pip3` is pointing to the wrong place? i.e. does `which pip3` give you the path to your conda-installed `pip3`?

Comment: Hi, no apperantly it doesn't: which pip3 --> ~/.local/bin/pip3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, when the package is installed by `pip` (that's what the channel `pypi` indicates) is to enable Conda to directly manipulate PyPI packages by [enabling the `pip_interop_enabled` configuration option](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/pip-interoperability.html). You can do this temporarily via:

```
CONDA_PIP_INTEROP_ENABLED=1 conda remove -n base keras
```

or you can turn this on globally

```
conda config --set pip_interop_enabled True
conda remove -n base keras
```

Just be aware that this is an experimental option, and I still strongly encourage following the best practice recommendations found in "[*Using Pip in a Conda Environment*](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)".

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend trying a couple of things:

1. do a `conda deactivate && conda activate base`. In my experience, conda can get into a bad state and this can help(even in the base environment). Then `pip uninstall keras`
2. If that doesn't work, you can try manually getting the path to your conda-installed `pip` and use that to uninstall `keras`.

Hope it helps.